# Duplicate Address Bar in page

Tags: url

I want to duplicate the address bar into an input field in the middle of my page.  I have tried using:

```
<form>
      <input type="url">
</form>
```

But this only takes a url and doesn't go to inputted url.

I have tried using ctrl-l but cannot get the javascript to work to force cursor position into the address bar.
    
        chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) {
            chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { 'url': url, 'selected': true });
        }
     
So when form loads, the cursor is always in the duplicate address bar.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML you can catch the url:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function setURLInput(){
   document.getElementById('myURL').value = document.URL;
}
</script>
<body onload="setURLInput()">
<form>
      <input id="myURL" type="url">
</form>
</body>
```

But with other language such as PHP, there is more elegant way to do it.